# Would this conditional statement work in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-comments, html5shiv

I want to only load the html5shiv.js file *if* the web browser is less than IE 9.

The code I have is

```
<doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]
      <script type="text/javascript" src="html5shiv.js"></script>
  -->
 </head>
 <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

When I test to see if this works or not (I do this by changing the Browser Mode option to a version lower than IE 9 in Developer Tools - I'm not clear as to whether this works or not.

Does this work for you - or is the code atleast *right*?

Comment: Well, your syntax is not right, http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: That's the same page where I got my conditional code from.

Comment: Looks like you copy/pasted wrong. Your doctype isn't correct either.

Comment: Oops sorry I accidently deleted the <html lang="en"> bit when I was formatting the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be missing a chevron at the end of the first line and the closing tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yeps, I'm waiting for the timer to run out. It makes me wait 15 minutes before I can accept any answer.

Comment: Angle brackets are also known as 'chevrons' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Angle_brackets_or_chevrons_.E2.9F.A8_.E2.9F.A9

Comment: @blurfus Interesting, I'll delete my comment :)